# Checking for each item in a list box if its bigger than 5

Tags: c#

I have to enter grades to a list box and then to see if they are bigger than 5. And if they are bigger than 5 store the ones who are. 
This is what i got so far ..

```
foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
{
    if(Convert.ToInt32(item.ToString())) == 5 )
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? Doesn´t this do what you expect it to? Any exceptions? Unexpexted results?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Where do you want to store them? What doesn't work?

Comment: It's trying to check if an object is == 5, but an object doesn't have a value

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq

```
bool bigger = listBox.Items.OfType<int>().Where(x => x > 5);
```

It might be usefull to convert the result to a list by using

```
List<int> filtered = listBox.Items.OfType<int>().Where(x => x > 5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 var largerThan5 = listBox.Items.Where(I => int.Parse(I.ToString()) > 5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use LINQ as listBox.Items are not implement IEnumerable.

Use this for example:

```
        for (var pos = 0; pos < listBox1.Items.Count; pos++)
        {
            int value;
            if (int.TryParse(listBox1.Items[pos]?.ToString(), out value) && value >= 5)
                Debug.WriteLine($"Index: {pos}, Value: {value}");
        }
```

Comment: This is not true, `ListBox.Items` is of type `ListBox.ObjectCollection`, which looks like this: `public class ObjectCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable`  It definitely implements IEnumerable.

Comment: Oh yeah! not implements IEnumerable<T>.
But still, you cannot write listBox.Items.Where(....)

Comment: But you can write `listBox.Items.OfType<int>().Where(...)`.